# wdio.ocr.service : Can't fetch the text with the help of ocrGetText() but screenshot are captured

Tags: javascript, appium, ocr, tesseract, webdriver-io

1. Node modules need to installed in wdio project for ocr

```js
     npm install wdio-ocr-service@next --save-dev  
     npm i tesseract.js
```

2. Added the below lines in `wdio.conf.js`.

```
      // wdio.conf.js
      exports.config = {
      //...
        services: [
             // your other services like appium
            [
              'ocr',
              {
                 // The OCR options
                  ocrImagesPath: 'ocr-images/',
                  ocrLanguage: 'eng'
               },
             ]
           ],
        };
```

3. with the help of `ocrGetText()`, trying to assert value but it failed.

```
          it('should be able to the the text of a screen', () => {
            // Assert that the word `PRODUCTS` is shown
                expect(driver.ocrGetText()).toContain('PRODUCTS')
    
            // OR assert with options
                expect(driver.ocrGetText(
                {
                    // to crop the image to fetch particular text
                    androidRectangles: {
                    top: 200,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 800,
                    bottom: 400,
               },
               reuseOcr:true,
             }
           )).toContain('PRODUCTS')
         })
```

**Expected** : The assertion should pass by validating the text.

**Actual** : Trying to fetch the text (`ocrGetText()`) from a particular screen for assertion but the value returned is `null`.

Comment: Please do not share pictures of code. Instead, please copy and paste relevant code into code blocks tags.